# Changing "from" value in elasticsearch query dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch query I have following:

> "from":0,
>     "size":100,

I have thousands of records in database which I want to fetch in batches of 100.
I process one batch, and then fetch next batch of 100 and so on. I know how many records are to be fetched in total.

So value for 'from' needs to be changed dynamically.
How can I modify "from" in code?

Edit: I am programming in groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this depending on what do you need it for-

1) First one is simply using pagination and you can keep updating the "from" variable by the desired result size in a loop till you have retrieved all the results (considering you have the total count at the start) , but the problem with this approach is - till 'from' is < 9000 it works fine, but after it exceeds 9000 you get this size restriction error-

```
"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [100000]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level setting"
```

which can be countered, as mentioned in the error by changing the index.max_result_window setting.However if you are instead planning to use this call as a one time operation(example for re-indexing) its is better to use to the scroll api as mentioned in the next point. (reference - [How to retrieve all documents(size greater than 10000) in an elasticsearch index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713268/how-to-retrieve-all-documentssize-greater-than-10000-in-an-elasticsearch-index) )

2) You can use the scroll api, something like this in java :

```
public String getJSONResponse() throws IOException {
        String res = "";
        int docParsed = 0;
        String fooResourceUrl
                = "http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?scroll=5m&size=100";
        ResponseEntity<String> response
                = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, String.class);

        JSONObject fulMappingOuter = (JSONObject) new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        String scroll_id = fulMappingOuter.getString("_scroll_id");
        JSONObject fulMapping = fulMappingOuter.getJSONObject("hits");

        int totDocCount = fulMapping.getInt("total");
        JSONArray hitsArr = (JSONArray) fulMapping.getJSONArray("hits");
        System.out.println("total hits:" + hitsArr.length());
        while (docParsed < totDocCount) {
            for (int i = 0; i < hitsArr.length(); i++) {
                docParsed++;
                //do your stuff
            }
            String uri
                    = "http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll";
            // set headers
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            JSONObject searchBody = new JSONObject();
            searchBody.put("scroll", "5m");
            searchBody.put("scroll_id", scroll_id);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(searchBody.toString(), headers);
            //    // send request and parse result
            ResponseEntity<String> responseScroll = restTemplate
                    .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
            fulMapping = (JSONObject) new JSONObject(responseScroll.getBody()).get("hits");
            hitsArr = (JSONArray) fulMapping.getJSONArray("hits");
            //        System.out.println("response when trying to upload to local: "+response.getBody());
        }

        return res;

    }
```

Calling the scroll api initialises a 'Scroller' . This returns the first set of results along with a scroll_id the number of results being 100 as set when creating the scroller in the first call. Notice the 5m in the first url's parameter? That is for setting the scroll time, that is the time in minutes for which ElasticSearch will keep the search context alive,if this time is expired, no results can be further fetched using this scroll id(also its a good practice to remove the scroll context if your job has finished before the scroll time expires, as keeping the scroll context alive is quite resource intensive) 
For each subsequent scroll request, the updated scroll_id is sent and next batch of results is returned.

Note: Here I have used Springboot's RestTemplate Client to make the calls and then parsed the response JSONs by using JSON parsers. However the same can be achieved by using elastic-search's own high level REST client for Groovy . here's a reference to the scroll api - 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search-scroll.html

Comment: ResponseEntity<String> responseScroll = restTemplate
                    .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
shouldn't it be HttpMethod.GET?

Comment: yes both GET or POST can be used and the URL should not include the index name — this is specified in the first request that creates the scroll instead.- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll